# React material-ui Slide not working when nested within another slide

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, slide

I have the following `SlidingPanel` component that utilises mui `Slide`.

Broadly speaking it does three things

1. It renders a child component `children` within it on a white card `id="SlidingPanel-card"`
2. Has a close button StyledIconButton `id="SlidingPanel-closeButton"` that closes the Slide on click
3. Has a darkened background `id="SlidingPanel-background"` that, when clicked, also closes the panel the same way the close icon does

In this case, my parent SlidingPanel is being rendered with a `FormComponent` prop, a basic form, and within that `FormComponent` there is another button that calls the child SlidingPanel.

The problem I have is when a SlidingPanel component is rendered and within it a nested SlidingPanel component is rendered, the parent background is not being overridden by the child background (`parent, child = blue, red` for debugging purposes) and specifically **when the child component is open, clicking on the background causes the parent component to also close despite preventing propagation even though the CloseButton `id="SlidingPanel-closeButton"` itself works as expected (closes child before parent), as it seems the child component renders no background at all**.

What am I doing wrong here? I am 2 days in the hole on this problem.

Thank you.

Relevant code snippets:

**The first call of SlidingPanel, overriding the default green background with blue for debugging purposes (it overrides correctly)**

```
<SlidingPanel
  bgColor="blue"
  closeButtonPushdownAmount={0}
  isOpen={isOpen}
  setIsOpen={setIsOpen}
  disableBackgroundClose={disableBackgroundClose}
>
  <FormComponent
    {...formProps}
    initialData={initialData}
    onOpenPanel={handleOpenPanel}
  />
</SlidingPanel>;
```

**The nested call of another SlidingPanel, overriding parent blue background to red for debugging (it does not change to red)**

```
<SlidingPanel
  bgColor="red"
  closeButtonPushdownAmount={1}
  isOpen={addFilterFormOpen} // Use the new state variable here
  setIsOpen={setAddFilterFormOpen} // Use the new setter function here
>
  <AddFilterForm
    onFilterSubmit={onFilterSubmit}
    // initialData={selectedFilterRule}
  />
</SlidingPanel>;
```

**SlidingPanel.js**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
// import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import Slide from '@mui/material/Slide';
import Card from '@mui/material/Card';
import { CardContent } from '@mui/material';
import CloseIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Close';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import { keyframes, css } from '@mui/system';
import StyledIconButton from './StyledIconButton';

const bounce = keyframes`
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  20% {
    transform: translate(-25px, 25px);
  }
  40% {
    transform: translate(15px, -15px);
  }
  60% {
    transform: translate(-10px, 10px);
  }
  80% {
    transform: translate(5px, -5px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
`;

const SlidingPanel = ({
  bgColor = 'green',
  isOpen = false, // Take an initial open state
  setIsOpen, // A function to set the open state
  disableBackgroundClose,
  closeButtonDisabled = false,
  closeButtonPushdownAmount = 0,
  children,
}) => {
  const [isPulsing, setIsPulsing] = useState(false);
  // const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleClose = (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    setIsOpen(false);

    // navigate('/portal/');
  };

  const handleKeyDown = (event) => {
    if (event.key === 'Escape') {
      setIsOpen(false);
      // navigate('/portal/');
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown);
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown);
    };
  }, []);

  console.log('bgColor', bgColor);

  return (
    <Slide
      id="SlidingPanel-slide"
      key={closeButtonPushdownAmount}
      direction="down"
      in={isOpen}
      mountOnEnter
      unmountOnExit
    >
      <Box
        id="SlidingPanel-background"
        sx={{
          position: 'fixed',
          top: 0,
          left: 0,
          width: '100%',
          height: '100%',
          zIndex: 1000 + closeButtonPushdownAmount,
          backgroundColor: isOpen ? bgColor : 'yellow', // change here
        }}
        onClick={(e) => {
          if (e.target !== e.currentTarget) return;

          e.stopPropagation();
          if (disableBackgroundClose) {
            setIsPulsing(true);
            setTimeout(() => setIsPulsing(false), 150);
          } else {
            handleClose(e);
          }
        }}
      >
        <Card
          id="SlidingPanel-card"
          sx={{
            position: 'absolute',
            top: '50%',
            left: '50%',
            transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)',
            width: '100%',
            maxWidth: '1500px',
            height: '100%',
            backgroundColor: 'white',
            boxShadow: '0 -4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)',
          }}
          onClick={(e) => e.stopPropagation()}
        >
          <StyledIconButton
            id="SlidingPanel-closeButton"
            disabled={closeButtonDisabled}
            sx={{
              position: 'absolute',
              right: 0,
              zIndex: 1000 + closeButtonPushdownAmount,
              animation: isPulsing
                ? css`
                    ${bounce} 1s ease-in-out
                  `
                : 'none',
            }}
            onClick={handleClose}
          >
            <CloseIcon />
          </StyledIconButton>
          <CardContent>{children}</CardContent>
        </Card>
      </Box>
    </Slide>
  );
};

export default SlidingPanel;
```